# Shaking the UIAlertView if user press Submit button when the textFields are empty

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uialertview

I want to shake the `UIAlertView` if a user presses the submit button without entering any data in the textFields. Is it possible in iOS?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly add inside header file add

```
int direction;
int shakes;
```

For preventing UIAlertView from dismissing. refer [keep-uialertview-displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9200616/keep-uialertview-displayed) link. also refer [prevent-alertview-dismissal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12802709/prevent-alertview-dismissal) link.

Use UIAlertView Delegate:

```
- (void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
  if (buttonIndex == 0)
    //do here something
  else if (buttonIndex == 1){
    if(txtField.text.length == 0 || txtField1.text.length == 0) //check your two textflied has value
    {
      direction = 1;
      shakes = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Add this method:

```
-(void)shake:(UIAlertView *)theOneYouWannaShake
{
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.03 animations:^
                                  {
                                    theOneYouWannaShake.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(5*direction, 0);
                                  } 
                                  completion:^(BOOL finished) 
                                  {
                                    if(shakes >= 10)
                                    {
                                      theOneYouWannaShake.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
                                      return;
                                    }
                                    shakes++;
                                    direction = direction * -1;
                                    [self shake:theOneYouWannaShake];
                                  }];
}
```

Refer [more here about animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294451/animating-uitextfield-to-indicate-a-wrong-password)

Comment: I like this approach, it's clean. Format a bit better/more consistently your code, though. +1.

Comment: i try this but my Alert shake and then disappear. I dont want it to disappear

Answer (score 1):

[ShakingAlertView](https://github.com/stringer630/ShakingAlertView) is a UIAlertView subclass that implements this functionality.

Disclaimer: I am the developer of ShakingAlertView

Answer (score 0):

Here the Code Call This Methods As validation Gets Failed

```
- (void)animateView 
{
  CAKeyframeAnimation *animation;
        animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
        animation.duration = 2.0;
        animation.cumulative = NO;
        animation.repeatCount = MAXFLOAT;
        animation.values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 0.0], 
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat: DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(-4.0)], 
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 0.0],
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat: DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(4.0)],
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 0.0], nil];
        animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth;
        animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
        animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
        [[alertView layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"effect"];
}
```

Call this Animation whenever you want to stop animation

```
- (void)stopAnimatiomn
{
    [[alertView layer] removeAnimationForKey:@"effect"];
}
```